Residue theorem application
First I want to provide a little bit of context: I finished my undergrad degree in physics in 2008 and after that I moved into strategic consulting and into the financial world. Right now, at 41 years old I decided to get back to Physics.
I was a good student, specially in theoretical and mathematical disciplines and I would be starting a PhD program next fall. Until then I have to catch up on the more important things and I have already started studying (the first month was hard but after than things got much better - I am now starting my fourth month of study) and right now I am in the particle physics part of my catching up.
Now that I removed the context out of the way let me share the problem I am trying to solve.
I am trying to solve an integral via the residue theorem but so far I have no luck on my side. The integral is this one:
$$ I=\int_0^\infty k^2dk\frac{\Lambda ^4}{(\Lambda ^2+p^2)^2}\frac{1}{p^2-k^2+i\epsilon}. $$
I should evaluate the integral in the non-relativistic approximation and also on the relativistic approximation - hence I should re-express $k$, $p$ in terms of each other or in terms of energy.
First we will evaluate the integrals using non-relativistic kinematics. For non-relativistic kinematics it is
$$ E=\frac{p^2}{2m} $$
and for $k$ it is
$$ k=\sqrt{2mE} $$
From the previous equation it follows
$$ dk=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}dE $$
Hence we can simplify our integral:
$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty k^2dk\frac{\Lambda ^4}{(\Lambda ^2+p^2)^2}\frac{1}{p^2-k^2+i\epsilon} &= \int_0^\infty 2mE \sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}\frac{\Lambda ^4}{(\Lambda ^2+2mE)^2}\frac{1}{2mE-2mE+i\epsilon} \\
&= \Lambda ^4 \dfrac{\sqrt{2m^3 E}}{i\epsilon}\int_0^\infty \frac{dE}{(\Lambda ^2+2mE)^2}
\end{aligned}$
I don't think I am in the right track at all.
I would appreciate if you could help me on one of the cases (relativistic or non-relativistic), because I know that if I see one of them I can easily do the other.

You said you are doing particle physics. That integral, which obviously comes from there, is also obviously meant to be relativistic. You should not try to do this with non-relativistic approximation, because you are far more likely to make a mistake. Your integral is of $k$ and so $\frac{\Lambda^4}{(\Lambda^2+p^2)^2}$ is a constant that you can take out of the integral. Is this problem even supposed to be using residue theorem or not?

Thank you. But $p$ also depends on $k$ since there is a functional relationship between momentum and the wave number.
if we consider the factor as a constant the integral would be divergent since the limit of $\lim k_{ \to \infty} \frac{k^2}{p^2-k^2+i\epsilon}=-1$
PS: Edited to correct typos

Then you need to tell us how precisely $p$ depends upon $k$; in fact, you should clarify where particularly you are getting this problem from, etc, so that we can judge if you have even gotten to this step correctly.

The formula is given so I was assuming it as being correct. But now that you mention it maybe I should start by checking out if the integral is indeed correct or not.
In the relativistic limit an using natural units it is $k=p$

Looks vaguely like Pauli-Villars regularization, but I'm not sure if the differences are due to the idiosyncrasies of your approach or just mistakes.

Thank you @LPZ. At first sight it does look similar. I will read more on it and see if it can help.
